# Access won't insert record to table from form if table already has a record in it

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

Essentially I have a table with the data and then I want a form that has a text box for each field in the table with a subtable of the main table incorporated into the form. The user fills in the text boxes with the information and then either adds it to the table or they can click on a record and edit it or delete it with the corresponding buttons on the form.

I was having some issues with some syntax and recently fixed that today, so now I'm finally fine tuning stuff on my form. The only issue I'm having now is that if there is already a record in the table, the form won't insert a new record once I click the add button. I fill the text boxes in and click the 'Add' button and the form refreshes like the add command worked, but then the new record doesn't show up in the table. However if I go back to the table and delete any record that is already in the table and then go back to the form and fill the boxes in again and click the 'Add' button, then a new record is inserted into the form.

I created a database before the one I'm currently working on and it works fine. It is very similar to the database that I'm working on now, so I just copied it and then renamed the fields and text boxes and everything to match the information that this database will be handling.

I have

Any ideas what's going on here and how I could fix?

Here's a link to some screenshots of the database: https://imgur.com/a/QvCY2

Here's my code:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    'when we click on button Add there are two options
    '1. for insert
    '2. for update
    If Me.txtICN.Tag & "" = "" Then
        'this is for insert new
        'add data to table
        CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblInventory(ICN, manu, model, serial, descr, dateRec, dateRem, dispo, flgDispo, project, AMCA, UL, comments) " & _
        " VALUES(" & Me.txtICN & ", '" & Me.txtManu & "', '" & Me.txtModel & "', '" & Me.txtSerial & "', '" & Me.txtDescr & "', '" & Me.txtDateRec & "', '" & Me.txtDateRem & "', '" & Me.txtDispo & "', '" & Me.chkFlg & "', '" & Me.txtProject & "', '" & Me.txtAMCA & "', '" & Me.txtUL & "', '" & Me.txtComments & "')"
    Else
        'otherwise (Tag of txtICN stores the ICN of item to be modified)
        CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblInventory " & _
        " SET ICN = " & Me.txtICN & _
        ", manu = '" & Me.txtManu & "'" & _
        ", model = '" & Me.txtModel & "'" & _
        ", serial = '" & Me.txtSerial & "'" & _
        ", descr = '" & Me.txtDescr & "'" & _
        ", dateRec = '" & Me.txtDateRec & "'" & _
        ", dateRem = '" & Me.txtDateRem & "'" & _
        ", dispo = '" & Me.txtDispo & "'" & _
        ", flgDispo = '" & Me.chkFlg & "'" & _
        ", project = '" & Me.txtProject & "'" & _
        ", AMCA = '" & Me.txtAMCA & "'" & _
        ", UL = '" & Me.txtUL & "'" & _
        ", comments = '" & Me.txtComments & "'" & _
        " WHERE ICN = " & Me.txtICN.Tag
    End If

    'clear form
    cmdClear_Click
    'refresh data in list on form
    frmInventorySub.Form.Requery

End Sub

Private Sub cmdClear_Click()
    Me.txtICN = ""
    Me.txtManu = ""
    Me.txtModel = ""
    Me.txtSerial = ""
    Me.txtDescr = ""
    Me.txtDateRec = ""
    Me.txtDateRem = ""
    Me.txtDispo = ""
    Me.chkFlg = ""
    Me.txtProject = ""
    Me.txtAMCA = ""
    Me.txtUL = ""
    Me.txtComments = ""

    'focus on ID text box
    Me.txtICN.SetFocus
    'set button edit to enable
    Me.cmdEdit.Enabled = True
    'change caption of button add to Add
    Me.cmdAdd.Caption = "Add"
    'clear tag on txtICN for reset new
    Me.txtICN.Tag = ""
End Sub

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    DoCmd.Close
End Sub

Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
    'delete record
    'check existing selected record
    If Not (Me.frmInventorySub.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.frmInventorySub.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
        'confirm delete
        If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this item?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            'delete now
            CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM tblInventory " & _
                "WHERE ICN =" & Me.frmInventorySub.Form.Recordset.Fields("ICN")
            'refresh data in list
            Me.frmInventorySub.Form.Requery
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdEdit_Click()
    'check whether there exists data in list
    If Not (Me.frmInventorySub.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.frmInventorySub.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
        'get data to text box control
        With Me.frmInventorySub.Form.Recordset
            Me.txtICN = .Fields("ICN")
            Me.txtManu = .Fields("manu")
            Me.txtModel = .Fields("model")
            Me.txtSerial = .Fields("serial")
            Me.txtDescr = .Fields("descr")
            Me.txtDateRec = .Fields("dateRec")
            Me.txtDateRem = .Fields("dateRem")
            Me.txtDispo = .Fields("dispo")
            Me.chkFlg = .Fields("flgDispo")
            Me.txtProject = .Fields("project")
            Me.txtAMCA = .Fields("AMCA")
            Me.txtUL = .Fields("UL")
            Me.txtComments = .Fields("comments")
            'store id of item in Tag of txtICN in case ICN is modified
            Me.txtICN.Tag = .Fields("ICN")
            'change caption of button add to Update
            Me.cmdAdd.Caption = "Update"
            'disable button edit
            Me.cmdEdit.Enabled = False
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: In your update string, try removing the `ICN = " & Me.txtICN` part, as there's no need to update that field (since you've selected that record already).   That's just a guess.

Comment: You have two potential issues. One is whether any of your fields are either set up as unique (in which case you have to make sure your new record is indeed unique for these fields) and the other is that you are not protecting your SQL code from special characters like `' (single quotes)`.

Comment: Why are you not using a bound form where recordsource is table? There will be no need for an append/update queries.

Comment: You are saving date values as strings in a text field? Doubt I would design an inventory database that deletes inventory records. Is this tracking individual assets or bulk quantities?

Comment: Why do keep on punishing yourself? Change the form to be bound to the table, and you can _erase all this stuff_ and get done with it.